# Duda sobre indexOf() en string

Tags: javascript, string

por favor si podrían darme mayor detalle de porque el retorno de cada ejercicio :

```
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Whale",0) // returns 5

"Blue Whale".indexOf("Whale",5) // returns 5

"Blue Whale".indexOf("",9)      // returns 9
```

Gracias.

Comment: aquí la explicación de la mozilla developer org, https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf

Answer (score 3):

1. El primero te retorna 5 por que lee la cadena de texto como un array de posiciones donde tu le dices que empiece desde la posición 0 y encuentra que la palabra Whale empieza en la posición 5
2. El segundo te regresa 5 por que encuentra que la primer coincidencia de la cadena de texto que declaras empieza en la posición 5
3. El tercero te regresa nueve por que en la función tu le estas indicando que encuentre desde la posición nueve la primer coincidencia que no tenga ni cadenas de texto, numeros, ni espacios en blanco y justo en esa posición es donde acaba tu cadena de texto y tiene pegadas unas comillas sin espacio por eso te regresa nueve por que si encuentra una coincidencia

> El método `indexOf` lee todo como una posición sea número, espacio en
>   blanco o cadena de texto

Aquí el ejemplo con cada uno de los escenarios propuestos en la pregunta

```js
let phrase = 'Blue Whale'

console.log(phrase.indexOf("Whale", 0))

console.log(phrase.indexOf("Whale", 5))

console.log(phrase.indexOf("", 9))
```

el método `indexOf()` al leer la cada de texto como un array; es como si la viera del modo siguiente

```
B L U E   W H A L E  => CADENA DE TEXTO
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  => POSICIÓN DENTRO DEL ARRAY DE CADA ELEMENTO
```